# C# Regex match all occurrences

Tags: c#, regex, match

I'm trying to make a Regular Expression in C# that will match strings like`"&#00;&#01;"`, but my Regex stops at the first match, and I'd like to match the whole string.

I've been trying with a lot of ways to do this, currently, my code looks like this:

```
string sPattern = @"/&#\d{2};/";
Regex rExp = new Regex(sPattern);
MatchCollection mcMatches = rExp.Matches(txtInput.Text);
foreach (Match m in mcMatches) {
    if (!m.Success) {
        //Give Warning
    }
}
```

And also tried `lblDebug.Text = Regex.IsMatch(txtInput.Text, "(&#[0-9]{2};)+").ToString();` but it also only finds the first match.

Any tips?

Edit:

The end result I'm seeking is that strings like `&#00;&#` are labeled as incorrect, as it is now, since only the first match is made, my code marks this as a correct string.

Second Edit:

I changed my code to this

```
string sPattern = @"&#\d{2};";
Regex rExp = new Regex(sPattern);

MatchCollection mcMatches = rExp.Matches(txtInput.Text);
int iMatchCount = 0;
foreach (Match m in mcMatches) {
    if (m.Success) {
        iMatchCount++;
    }
}

int iTotalStrings = txtInput.Text.Length / 5;
int iVerify = txtInput.Text.Length % 5;

if (iTotalStrings == iMatchCount && iVerify == 0) {
    lblDebug.Text = "True";
} else {
    lblDebug.Text = "False";
}
```

And this works the way I expected, but I still think this can be achieved in a better way.

Third Edit:
As @devundef suggest, the expression `"^(&#\d{2};)+$"` does the work I was hopping, so with this, my final code looks like this:

```
string sPattern = @"^(&#\d{2};)+$";
Regex rExp = new Regex(sPattern);
lblDebug.Text = rExp.IsMatch(txtInput.Text).ToString();
```

I always neglect the start and end of string characters (^ / $).

Comment: The `MatchCollection` returned by `regex.Matches(input)` will by definition contain only `Match` instances with property `Success==true`. The body of your `if` statement will never execute.

Comment: It only shows 1 match, but I just found tha changing the expression to 
string sPattern = @"&#\d{2};"; does gives 2 matches if they are correct

Comment: What end result are you looking for? Are you looking to extract the numeric value or the whole element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `/` at the start and end of the expression.

```
string sPattern = @"&#\d{2};";
```

EDIT

I tested the pattern and it works as expected. Not sure what you want.

Two options:

`&#\d{2};` => will give N matches in the string. On the string `&#00;&#01;` it will match 2 groups,  `&#00;` and `&#01;`

`(&#\d{2};)+` => will macth the whole string as one single group. On the string `&#00;&#01;` it will match 1 group, `&#00;&#01;`

Edit 2:

What you want is not get the groups but know if the string is in the right format. This is the pattern:

```
Regex rExp = new Regex(@"^(&#\d{2};)+$");

var isValid = rExp.IsMatch("&#00;&#01;") // isValid = true
var isValid = rExp.IsMatch("&#00;xyz&#01;") // isValid = false
```

Comment: I tried this also, but it still doesn't work the way I expected

Comment: This expression will give n Match objects, where n is the number of repetitions you have in the string. What exatcly do you want?

Comment: I wanted to return if the string as a whole matches the pattern, not just the first match or the number of matches. In all the ways I tried before, if the string was "&#00;&#10;&#", the number of matches would have been 2, but the string was not in the correct format. I edited my question to show what I have done now, and that way it works, but I still think it can be made in a better way.

Comment: I always fail to neglect the start and end of string in regular expressions (^ / $), you're correct, the expressions goes as "^(&#\d{2};)+$"

Answer (score 1):

Here you go: `(&#\d{2};)+` This should work for one occurence or more

Comment: I tried this previously, but this regex takes "&#00;&" as a valid string

Answer (score 0):

(&#\d{2};)*

Recommend:  http://www.weitz.de/regex-coach/

Comment: This is incorrect, "ANYTHING IN HERE" would be a correct string